# How to connect two building 5km apart from eachother?

Tags: networking, vpn, wifi

I have to design a network and give an estimate of the cost of all the equipment.

Now I have 3 building 100m apart which I'll connect with Fiber without a problem. Two of those though are connected with another building which is **5km** away.

Obviously you can't lay down 5km of fiber, so what's the best way to do this?

I thought of a **VPN**, but I don't know how it would perform given that there are almost 250 user on the network.

Else some kind of **Wireless** connection could work fine but I don't know what tecnology is used in real world situations(Wiimax maybe?)

I don't need you to do my homework, just an input to provide a solution that would work in an everyday situation.
Thank You.

Comment: I went to an interview with a school and they had a microwave link between the sites. Expensive, but worth it.

Comment: I'm hearing a lot of good things about the Unifi point-to-point wireless, and it's crazy cheap.  Might be worth investigating.

Comment: unifi has a range too small for my use, but their airmax solution look nice. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can work with your ISP to have multiple locations connected via MPLS or you can use a site to site VPN. These are the two most common solutions. [Metro Ethernet](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_Ethernet) may also be an option depending on your provider.

Basically, you should call your ISP and ask how they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The company i work for has a private 1 gigabit ether net connection between the office and the data-center, this is provided by the ISP, i don't know the exact details but according to our IT-personal, this connection is physically attached to both ends, making it impossible to pickup traffic on the line unless you are directly connected to the network.